# scrollHeight не работает

Tags: javascript

При изменении ширины окна браузера прекрасно работает

```
document.body.scrollWidth;
```

А вот scrollHeight при изменении высоты окна выдает одно и тоже число, по-моему равное высоте divа в окне. Как определить фактическую высоту окна? (Необходимо, чтобы всплывающая подсказка появлялась внизу окна независимо от его размера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А она и не должна меняться, это же высота "виртуального" окна. Документатция [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.scrollHeight).

Вам нужно

```
$(window).height()
```

(если вы используете jQuery). Если нет, воспользуйтесь советом [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1823700/276994). Если вам не нужна совместимость со старыми версиями IE, скажите просто

```
window.innerHeight
```

Comment: Какой тогда хитростью вычислить координаты ?(см.вопрос)

Comment: @Deus: CSS `position:fixed`?

Comment: @Deus: вот вам пример: http://mark-allen.net/notes/layout/footer/ Пусть за вас считает браузер :)

Comment: Спасибо, советы дельные, jQuery может все (must die), интересовало конкретное решение.

Comment: @Deus: пожалуйста!